# Linking a Racket program to a Fortran library

Tags: linker, racket, raco

I have a Racket program I want to link against a Fortran library and another library, because the Fortran API works well.  I saw from a Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609164/calling-a-fortran-routine-as-a-scheme-function) by Jens Axel Søgaard that he was able to link to CBLAS and LAPACK.  The libraries I'm using are different, but I'm hoping I'll be able to use them from Racket.  It would be quite sweet.

My question I think is simple.  Currently I build Racket programs that can execute on the required platform (Windows) like this:

```
$ raco exe -o MyProgram.exe MyProgram.rkt
$ raco distribute win MyProgram.exe
```

In the above, I was not compiling against or linking to anyone else's Fortran library.  Now that I will be, what will my `raco` command(s) look like?  Assume I have two libraries I need to link against:  `${LIBPATH}/libeccodes_f90.dll ${LIBPATH}/libeccodes.dll`

Answer (score 2):

The FFI in Racket uses libffi to dynamically load library files.

If it is possible to use the Fortran library from a C program,
then it should be possible to use it from Racket too.

I am a bit unsure whether the LAPACK library I used was produced
by a Fortran compiler - or whether something was done to make
it usable from C.

If you pass the `++lib` flag to `raco exe` the produced executable
should include the shared library. The exact details I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @soegaard!  I'll try that.